# How do we redirect the output of 1 ffmpeg processing as input in the same command?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to attach 2 videos using hstack filter and this is what I am doing, resizing 1 of the video files (to match same height) and then proceeding to merge. This is happening as 2 different steps,

1. `ffmpeg -y -i inputVideo1 -vf scale=-2:900 outputVideo1`
2. `ffmpeg -y -i outputVideo1 -i inputVideo2 -c:v libx264 -filter_complex hstack outputVideo2.mp4`

This is taking longer time. How do I make this happen in a single step? Something like,

````
ffmpeg -i inputVideo1 (something here) outputVideo1 (take this as input) -i inputVideo2 (hstack and stuff) outputVideo2.mp4```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -i inputVideo1 -i inputVideo2 -c:v libx264 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-2:900[left];[left][1:v]hstack" outputVideo.mp4
```